# How to throttle non-logged in users

Tags: server, jwt, throttling, rate-limiting

We can throttle logged-in users in our application code by inspecting the JWT and looking at how many requests they made in the last minute etc. But is there a good methodology to throttle non-logged in users? By IP address or something else?

Comment: You could throttle by IP, perhaps 1 implementation would be to cache the request count per IP. StackOverflow used this type of implementation in the past

Comment: right, so if they were logged-in, it would bypass the cache/redis. but if the weren't logged-in, then we'd use redis/cache?

Comment: I realized the other day that using a JWT for the throttling wasn't going to work b/c a malicious user could send 1000 requests at a time, and the JWT wouldn't be updated in time.

Comment: If they sent 1000 at a time, that’s ok. You can still create some throttle based on ip.